# Función con if para hacer merge basado en dos columnas o tres en pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy intentando resolver un problema interesante y me gustaría escuchar sus sugerencias.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es un merge de dos dataframes en tres columnas pero si la tercera en el primer dataframe tiene un valor nan entonces que el merge se haga con las primeras dos.

Ejemplo:

---DataFrame 1---

| Number | Number2 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | One |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 2 | Three |

---DataFrame 2---

| Number | Number2 | Name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | One |
| 2 | 2 | Two |
| 2 | 2 | Two.5 |
| 3 | 2 | Three |
| 3 | 2 | Three.5 |
| 4 | 2 | Four |

---Result---

| Number | Number2 | Name | Name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | One | One |
| 2 | 2 |  | Two |
| 2 | 2 |  | Two.5 |
| 3 | 2 | Three | Three |

Por el momento intenté hacer esta función.

```
def merge_three_or_two(row):
        if row['Name'] == np.nan:
            row = pd.merge(row, df2,  how='left', left_on=['Number','Number2'], right_on = ['Number','Number2'])
        else:
            row = pd.merge(row, df2,  how='left', left_on=['Number','Number2','Name'], right_on = ['Number','Number2','Name2'])
    
df1 = df1.apply(merge_three_or_two, axis=1)
```

De igual manera alguien me sugirió esta solución pero realmente solo resuelve el caso para hacer el merge con dos columnas, en ningún momento conidera hacerlo con las tres:

```
if df1.Name.isna().any():
    print(df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['Number', 'Number2']))
else:
    print(df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['Number','Number2','Name'], right_on = ['Number','Number2','Name2']))
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la lógica detrás de relacionar las columnas? Con lo que se puede ver no se entiende, tanto `Number` como `Number2` tiene valores repetidos.

Comment: Lo que busco relacionar es, en el caso de que Name esté vacío, que solo se haga un left join basado en la combinación de Number y Number2 por ambas columnas, entonces su resultado en Name estará vacío pero podría tener una variedad de filas con distintos valores en Name2. Mientras que, al momento de que Name sí tenga datos entonces que el merge se haga por la combinación de Number, Number 2 y Name, por ende en esas, Name2 solo tendrá el mismo valor de Name por combinación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función pd.merge() de Pandas para hacer un merge de dos dataframes. Esta función tiene varios parámetros que te permiten controlar cómo se realiza el merge. Para hacer un merge en tres columnas, puedes especificar las columnas en el parámetro on. Si quieres que el merge se haga en las primeras dos columnas cuando la tercera columna tiene un valor NaN, puedes usar la función pd.notnull() para filtrar el primer dataframe y quedarte solo con las filas que tienen un valor no nulo en la tercera columna. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
import pandas as pd

# supongamos que df1 y df2 son tus dataframes
# y que quieres hacer el merge en las columnas 'A', 'B' y 'C' de df1 y df2

# primero filtramos df1 para quedarnos solo con las filas que tienen un valor no nulo en la columna 'C'
df1_filtered = df1[pd.notnull(df1['C'])]

# hacemos el merge usando las columnas 'A', 'B' y 'C' como claves
df_merged = pd.merge(df1_filtered, df2, on=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# si quieres incluir las filas de df1 que tenían valor nulo en la columna 'C', puedes hacer un merge adicional usando solo las columnas 'A' y 'B' como claves
df_merged_all = pd.merge(df_merged, df1[pd.isnull(df1['C'])], on=['A', 'B'], how='outer')
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema. Si tienes alguna duda o necesitas más información, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia pero no es lo que busca mi problema. Lo que necesito hacer es, como mencioné, mezclas basado en dos columnas en las filas que estén vacías en la tercera y, en el caso contrario, mezclar basado en las tres.